# If $u$ is a homegenous function of degree $n$, show it satisfies the first order PDE $u_{x}+yu_{y}=nu$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Can you provide me with at least a hint, please? I have thought about a few things, but they have not got me anywhere. Thank you so much!

Comment: Write down the definition of "homogeneous of degree n" and differentiate with respect to the parameter.

Comment: ... as described [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulersHomogeneousFunctionTheorem.html)

Comment: @Dougl. Do you know the method of characteristic to solve the first order linear PESs? Apply it and find $$u(x,y)=e^{nx}F(ye^{-x})$$ $F$ is an arbitrary function.